# Swift OSX - set NSImage on IKImageView

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to set an image from NSImage on an IKImageView. I have already get the CGImage from the NSImage using NSImage.cgImage, but to set it on the IKImageView I need the properties of the image. How can I get these properties?

```
import Cocoa
import Quartz

class AjustarImagemViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imagemIKImageView: IKImageView!

    var imagem: NSImage? //Receive an image from another view

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(imagem)

        if let imagemRecebida = imagem {


            let cgImagem = imagemRecebida.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil)

            imagemIKImageView.setImage(cgImagem, imageProperties: [AnyHashable : Any])
        }
    }

    @IBAction func voltarButtonClicked(_ sender: NSButton) {

        dismiss(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried passing empty dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
CGImageSourceRef source;

source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)[cgImagem TIFFRepresentation], NULL);

NSDictionary* props = (NSDictionary*)CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);

imagemIKImageView.setImage(cgImagem, imageProperties: props)
```

Comment: Since you've used `CGImageSourceCreateWithData` you need to call `CFRelease(source)`. ARC doesn't apply to ImageIO, and without releasing source, you just created a memory leak.